# How to secure the communication between a SQL Server database and a c# administrative tool?

Tags: c#, security, sql-server-2008, encryption, communication

How can I secure the communication between a C# program running locally on my computer and a SQL Server in a hosted environment?

I have an asp.net application that is secured by SSL encryption. So using the asp.net from an open wlan connection is no problem.

How can I achieve the same kind of encryption for my administrative tool? Would it be best to write a service? But how would that connection to the service be secured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply specify encryption in the connection string like so:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False
;Initial Catalog="Foo";Data Source=(local);Use Encryption for Data=True;
```

This connection string uses the Native Client and a trusted connection but obviously can be adjusted for a SQL username and password.

For more, see the "Enable encryption for a specific client" section of this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898). You have to ensure that the client has the server's certificate in its Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder. [Here is another article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500.aspx)